# Перенос вывода в Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: Скрин из Jupyter notebook]

Jupyter notebook
Как сделать так, чтобы вывод не переносился на новую строчку?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Python pandas, how to widen output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11707586/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого достаточно установить:

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

Чтобы посмотреть какие есть еще параметры вывода в Pandas наберите `pd.options.display.` и нажмите кнопку `Tab`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]